# How can I display only specified database results based on TListbox items?

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have two forms: *frmMakeQuote* and *frmQuoteTemp*

In the *frmMakeQuote* there are two *TListboxes*: *lboMtrlList* and *lboSelectedMtrl*

*lboMtrlList* displays the *Product Description* column from the database.

```
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
  con.LoginPrompt := false;
  con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=C:\Users\kasio\Documents\Embarcadero\' +
    'Studio\Projects\ProgramDatabase;');
  query.Connection := con;

  query.SQL.Text :=
    'SELECT [Material Description] FROM MtrlDatabase ORDER BY MtrlID';
  try
    query.Open;
    lboMtrlList.Items.Clear;
    while not query.EOF do
    begin
      lboMtrlList.Items.Add(query.Fields[0].AsString);
      query.Next;
    end;
  finally
    query.Close;
  end;
end;
```

When the person double clicks on any 'product' in the *lboMtrlList*, it's moved to the *lboSelectedMtrl*. (Basically, it shows the selected 'products'.)

```
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.lboMtrlListDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  lboSelectedMtrl.Items.Add(lboMtrlList.Items.Strings[lboMtrlList.ItemIndex]);
end;
```

I want to be able to display the *Product Description* and *Price* columns from the database, of ONLY the selected 'products' from the *lboSelectedMtrl*. They should be displayed in the TStringGrid called *sgdMaterials* on the *frmQuoteTemp*.

I wrote something like this:

```
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.performMtrlQuery;
var
  i: integer;
begin
   for i := 1 to frmMakeQuote.lboSelectedMtrl.ItemIndex do
   begin
  query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT [Material Description], Price FROM MtrlDatabase ' +
   'WHERE [Material Description] = "'
   + frmMakeQuote.lboSelectedMtrl.Items.Strings[1]
   + '" ORDER BY MtrlID';
  query.Open;
  query.First;
   end;
end;
```

It doesn't show any error, but it doesn't work and displays nothing and I'm aware that it's probably completely wrong.

Comment: Is this homework?  Don't let this be homework.  :-)

Comment: Your `performMtrlQuery` makes no effort to display anything. It merely opens the query. If you want to display the data, you'll need to either write to the cells of the stringgrid or (better) use a `TDBGrid`, which is specifically designed to display data from a dataset. There are tutorials in the Delphi documentation about writing database applications. I'd highly suggest you work your way through them. You can learn about parameterized queries and data-aware controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop inside of `performMtrlQuery()` is wrong.  If nothing is actually selected in `lboSelectedMtrl`, its `ItemIndex` will be -1 and the loop will not iterate through any items.  Not only that, but even if an item were selected, your loop would not iterate through ALL of the available items.  Also, when you are indexing into the `Strings[]` property, you are using a hard-coded `1` instead of the loop variable `i`.

As for your `TStringGrid`, why not use a `TDBGrid` instead, and tie it to a DataSource that is filtering the database by the desired items?  In any case, `performMtrlQuery()` is not doing anything to populate the grid at all, whether it is to store the search results in the grid directly, or to store the results in a list somewhere that `frmQuoteTemp` can then read from.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.performMtrlQuery;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to frmMakeQuote.lboSelectedMtrl.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
    query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT [Material Description], Price FROM MtrlDatabase' +
      ' WHERE [Material Description] = "'
      + frmMakeQuote.lboSelectedMtrl.Items.Strings[i]
      + '" ORDER BY MtrlID';
    query.Open;
    query.First;
    // do something with query.Fields[0] and query.Fields[1] ...
    query.Close;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, searching your materials by their descriptions is not the most efficient search option.  You should search by their IDs instead.  I would suggest an alternative approach to accomplish that - use your `TListBox` controls in virtual mode (`Style=lbVirtual`) instead, and store your search results in separate `TStringList` objects.  That way you can store both IDs and Descriptions together in memory while displaying the descriptions in the UI and using the IDs in queries.

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  allmaterials := TStringList.Create;
  selectedmaterials := TStringList.Create;

  con := TFDConnection.Create(Self);
  con.LoginPrompt := false;
  con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=C:\Users\kasio\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\ProgramDatabase;');

  query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
  query.Connection := con;
  query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT MtrlID, [Material Description] FROM MtrlDatabase ORDER BY MtrlID';
  try
    query.Open;
    while not query.EOF do
    begin
      allmaterials.Add(query.Fields[0].AsString + '=' + query.Fields[1].AsString);
      query.Next;
    end;
  finally
    query.Close;
  end;

  lboMtrlList.Count = allmaterials.Count;
end;

procedure TfrmMakeQuote.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  allmaterials.Free;
  selectedmaterials.Free;
end;

// lboMtrlList OnData event handler
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.lboMtrlListData(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; var Data: string);
begin
  Data := allmaterials.ValueFromIndex[Index];
end;

// lboSelectedMtrl OnData event handler
procedure TfrmMakeQuote.lboSelectedMtrlData(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; var Data: string);
begin
  Data := selectedmaterials.ValueFromIndex[Index];
end;

procedure TfrmMakeQuote.lboMtrlListDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Idx := lboMtrlList.ItemIndex;
  if Idx = -1 then Exit;
  if selectedmaterials.IndexOfName(allmaterials.Names[Idx]) <> -1 then Exit;
  selectedmaterials.Add(allmaterials.Strings[Idx]);
  lboSelectedMtrl.Count := selectedmaterials.Count;
end;

procedure TfrmMakeQuote.performMtrlQuery;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to selectedmaterials.Count-1 do
  begin
    query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT [Material Description], Price FROM MtrlDatabase' +
      ' WHERE MtrlID = '
      + selectedmaterials.Names[i];
    query.Open;
    query.First;
    // do something with query.Fields[0] and query.Fields[1] ...
    query.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Lastly, if you switch to a single `TCheckListBox` or `TListView` control instead of 2 `TListBox` controls, you can take advantage of their ability to have checkboxes on each item, then you don't need to deal with the `OnDblClick` event anymore, and don't need to show two copies of your materials in your UI.  The user can just check the desired items before invoking `performMtrlQuery()`.

I would also suggest using a virtual `TListView` for the search results instead of a `TStringGrid`.  The UI will look better (`TStringGrid` is not the best looking UI control), and you can utilize memory more efficiently (`TStringGrid` can be a memory hog if you have a lot of data to display).

Comment: I tried, but the results are the same and nothing is displayed.